# Load Collada/image data stored in a multipart file into three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have Collada and related image data stored in a multipart file that is outputted from an application. I need to be able to load the Collada object and images for display in the Web via three.js. Can three.js interpret the multipart file or the data within the file, or does this need to be parsed out into actual files, since the Collada loader example shows it linking to a .dae file (ex. loader.load('models/monster.dae') and not the actual data.

In any case, how would I achieve this? The end goal is to load and view the "box" represented by the multipart data in the file.

Here is the sample structure of the multipart file I receive from the application:

```
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461"

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=Texture_1.png
Content-ID: response-1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Texture_1.png

‰PNG
"blob data here"

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=manifest.xml
Content-ID: response-2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dae_root>blank_3D.dae</dae_root>

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=texture_3D.dae
Content-ID: response-3
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=texture_3D.dae

<xml data here... lots of xml data>

------=_Part_4_153315749.1440434094461
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=Texture_0.png
Content-ID: response-4
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Texture_0.png

‰PNG
"blob image data"
```

**UPDATE:**

By having the vendor split up the files, I am able to load the collada file directly into the viewer... but I don't know how to get the images along with it loaded into memory or elsewise. Any ideas of how to include the images/textures that belong with the collada file? Here is my current loading code:

```
    // instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load('http://applicationvendorapi.com/dae', function (collada) {

        box = collada.scene;

        box.traverse(function (child) {

            if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

                var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                animation.play();

            }
        });

        box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
        box.updateMatrix();

        init();
        animate();
    });
```

The location of the textures tend to be in the same directory as the Collada file. Here is the XML of the Collada. The question is can I reference these by pulling in the other images over the Web service (ex. /endpoint/texture_0 and /endpoint/texture_1

```
<library_images>
<image id="Texture_0_png">
  <init_from>./Texture_0.png</init_from>
</image>
<image id="Texture_1_png">
  <init_from>./Texture_1.png</init_from>
</image>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Using the advice of @gaitat, I am attempting to load the texture first via the ImageUtils. However, it never makes the call to the URL for the texture/load the texture. It does however, still make the object call. Here is the current object wrapped in a texture call:

```
// Load texture before loading and initializing 3D object
    var texture0 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vendorwebservice/texture_0', {}, function loaded() {
        // Instantiate a Collada loader
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        loader.load('http://vendorwebservice/dae', function (collada) {

            box = collada.scene;

            box.traverse(function (child) {

                if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

                    var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                    animation.play();

                }
            });

            box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
            box.updateMatrix();

            init();
            animate();
        });

    });
```

Here is where it gets interesting. Since the DAE file I pull in has the following xml references to its textures, it actually tries to "get" these as well, but an endpoint does not exist with the .png extension so it fails (ex. http://vendorwebservice/texture_0.png):

```
<library_images>
<image id="Texture_0_png">
  <init_from>./Texture_0.png</init_from>
</image>
<image id="Texture_1_png">
  <init_from>./Texture_1.png</init_from>
</image>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88765/discussion-on-question-by-kode-load-collada-image-data-stored-in-a-multipart-fil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your application is a web-service where data does not have static URI's you need to download the data the service returns locally. As long as the texture files that the Collada file references are in a relative path (to the .dae), the THREE.ColladaLoader() will be able to find them, load them and display them.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but I hope my answer to help future readers.

I was in a similar situation where the files are not referenced by static URI. I didn't want to download the files because I concerned about some inefficiency of data traveling through network and taking up the server's resource. So I decided to handle it manually on browser by this process:

1. Read the name of the image file that the collada's texture is referencing
2. Find the image file with the name you found in step 1
3. Generate Threejs texture using the file you found in step 2
4. Connect the texture you made in step 3 to the texture slot in collada material

And here's an example code. In my case, the URLs in the code is data URL

```
const loadCollada = async (dae, img) => {
  const collada = new ColladaLoader().load(dae.url);

  // Get all materials in the loaded collada
  const materials = new Set();
  collada.traverse((object) => {
    const mat = object.material
    if (mat) {
      if (mat.constructor.name === "Array") {
        mat.forEach((e) => {
          materials.add(e);  
        })
      } else {
        materials.add(mat);
      }
    }
  });

  // Parse collada file
  const daeText = await fetch(dae.url).then((r) => r.text())
  const daeXml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(daeText,"text/xml")
  const materialLibrary = daeXml.getElementsByTagName("material")

  // Get material name and texture name(image file name)
  Array.from(materialLibrary).forEach((e) => {
    const materialName = e.getAttribute("name")
    const effect = e.getElementsByTagName("instance_effect")[0]
    const textureUrl = effect.attributes.url.value.slice(1)
    const textureTag = daeXml.getElementById(textureUrl)
    const textureName = textureTag.getElementsByTagName("init_from")[0]?.innerHTML

    // Find the material that matches name
    if (textureName) {
      Array.from(materials).forEach((mat) => {
        if (mat.name === materialName) {
          // Generate a texture and override it to the material we found
          const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(img[textureName].url)
          texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
          texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
          mat.map = texture
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```